# Transpose Rows Into Columns by Delimiter Column Name and Column Title

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm slightly stuck on this issue and need some SQL assistance please. Iv got a hierarchy table from someone who needs help transposing it and putting them into actual columns of another table. Here is a sample line of the table post querying it. I don't have access to adjust anything besides working from this table result:

```
SELECT ID, Path, Path_Values 
FROM TABLE1
```

Output:

```
ID  | Path                      | Path_Data_Values
----+---------------------------+----------------------------------
1   | Root                      | Org
2   | Root / Hemisphere         | Org / North Hemisphere
3   | Root / Hemisphere / State | Org / North Hemisphere / Texas
4   | Root / State              | Org / Texas
```

The above table can go to around 10 levels deep. Anyways I thankfully know the maximum depth of the final table and I have access to where the results should be stored its just above converting the above results to read the path and decide the appropriate column for it and then inserting the value into the end table.

Visual example of this end table (Desired Result):

```
ID | Root | Hemisphere           | State | Other_1 | Other_2 | Other_3
---+------+----------------------+-------+---------+---------+----------
 1 | Org  | NULL                 | NULL  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
 2 | Org  | Northern Hemisphere  | NULL  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
 3 | Org  | Northern Hemisphere  | Texas | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
 4 | Org  | NULL                 | Texas | NULL    | NULL    | NULL
```

Comment: This isn't hierarchy data, this is delimited data, that changes it's definition for every row; making things a real pain to work with. I assume this exercise is to fix this problem, so that you don't have to have this data stored like it is anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gets you most of the way there. As, however, the definition of your data changes from row to row, then there's no way to get the data in the order you want if you want to do it dynamically. (for Example should state be in position 2 or 3, as it appears in both? Without knowlegde of your data, or a look up table, that is impossible. This is a dynamic solution, however, it shows you the code it generates to get the results you're after, if you want to manually code all of your positions.

This also makes use of [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2), as `STRING_SPLIT` does not supply the ordinal position of a item in a delimited list; making it useless here.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int,
                            [Path] varchar(8000),
                            Path_Data_Values varchar(8000));
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(ID, [Path], Path_Data_Values)
VALUES (1,'Root','Org'),
       (2,'Root / Hemisphere','Org / North Hemisphere'),
       (3,'Root / Hemisphere / State','Org / North Hemisphere / Texas'),
       (4,'Root / State','Org / Texas');

GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT YT.ID,' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
                         N'       MAX(CASE P.Item WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(P.Item,'''') + N' THEN PDV.Item END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(P.Item)
                  FROM dbo.YourTable YT
                       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(YT.[Path],' / ','|')))V([Path])
                       CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.[Path],'|') P
                  GROUP BY P.Item
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,3,N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM dbo.YourTable YT' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(YT.[Path],'' / '',''|''),REPLACE(YT.Path_Data_Values,'' / '',''|'')))V([Path],Path_Data_Values)' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.[Path],''|'') P' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'     CROSS APPLY(SELECT DS.Item FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.Path_Data_Values,''|'') DS WHERE P.ItemNumber = DS.ItemNumber) PDV' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'GROUP BY YT.ID;';

PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Larnu, I added in the ID 5 to my initial example by myself as I wanted to account for something that might pop up in the data which may provide another spin on things but as of the sample I had its not in the current data set. 

Im quickly going to try your example now. Shall report back shortly.

Comment: Thank you Larnu, I got it resolved with this and the DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD function. Interesting function that so glad I got to learn something new along the way.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Larnu's sample data, I was able to post another way to do this.
This way is to construct a `values` clause to select from using dynamic SQL.

```
-- Get the maximum number of columns
DECLARE @ColumnsCount int = 
(SELECT MAX(LEN(Path_Data_Values) - LEN(REPLACE(Path_Data_Values, ' / ', '  '))) 
FROM YourTAble                               
)

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM (VALUES' + 

STUFF(
(
    -- Construct the values clause
    SELECT ',(''' + REPLACE(data, ' / ', ''',''') + ''')'
    FROM 
    (
        -- use Replicate to add the "missing" values to each line
        SELECT Path_Data_Values + REPLICATE(' / ', @ColumnsCount - (LEN(Path_Data_Values) - LEN(REPLACE(Path_Data_Values, ' / ', '  ')))) As data
        FROM YourTAble
    ) x
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
+ ') V (' + 
STUFF(
(
    -- Construct the values names
    SELECT ',' + REPLACE(Path, ' / ', ',')
    FROM YourTAble
    WHERE LEN(Path) - LEN(REPLACE(Path, ' / ', '  ')) = @ColumnsCount 
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
+ ')';

-- Whenever using dynamic SQL, Print is your best friend
PRINT @Sql

-- this will print, with the sample data provided, the following SQL statement:

-- SELECT * FROM (VALUES('Org','',''),('Org','North Hemisphere',''),('Org','North Hemisphere','Texas'),('Org','Texas','')) V (Root,Hemisphere,State) 

-- unremark once print gets you the desired sql
--EXEC(@Sql)
```

The result of the `exec(sql)` for the given sample data would be this:

```
Root    Hemisphere          State
Org     
Org     North Hemisphere    
Org     North Hemisphere    Texas
Org                         Texas
```

If you want `null` instead of empty strings, it's as easy as replacing `''` with `null` in the constructed dynamic SQL.

Please note that for 2017 version or higher, you can simplify this by using [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of the `stuff` and `for xml` combination I used.

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](https://rextester.com/HEROV48753)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to create a table of row numbers and then pivot?

e.g.

```
with cte_t
as
(
    Select * From
    (
    values(1,'Root','Org'),(2,'Root / Hemisphere','Org / North Hemisphere'),(3,'Root / Hemisphere / State','Org / North Hemisphere / Texas'),(4,'Root / State','Org / Texas')
    ) as t (ID,ThePath,Path_data_Values)
)

SELECT t1.[Id], [x].[value] as ThePath, x.[rn1], [x2].[value] as Path_data_Values, x2.[rn2] -- t1.ThePath,t1.Path_data_Values
FROM cte_t AS t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT v1.[value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.[Id] ORDER BY t1.[Id]) AS RN1 FROM STRING_SPLIT(t1.ThePath, '/') AS [v1]) AS x
CROSS APPLY (SELECT v2.[value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.[Id] ORDER BY t1.[Id]) AS RN2 FROM STRING_SPLIT(t1.Path_data_Values, '/') AS [v2]) AS x2
```